# chain promises in map loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, indexeddb

i know that there are plenty of posts on this topic, but i couldn't figure it out. I'm new to all this promise-thing, but i got a specific problem that needs to be solved. In the code below i loop through an array 'fnFoes' and within this fnFoes trough another array 'avatar'. For each element in avatar an svg-Code from an indexedDB is loaded and appended to html. My problem is: I want this function to fully load and append all svg before finishing the function and going on to the next function.

I tried to wrap the entire function into a promis but it still went on before having loaded all svg. I assume that this has to do with the indexedDB, but honestly, i just don't get it.

After 2 days of post reading and trial and error, Any help is much appreciated!!
Thx
Fritz

```
$.map(fnFoes, function(i,obj){ 
        console.log(obj);
        console.log('loadAllAvatars: checking foe: ' + obj);

        if (!(obj in foes) || fnFoes[obj].avatar != foes[obj].avatar || document.getElementById(obj) === null){ // compare avatar information of both variables. if changed, render new
            console.log('loadAllAvatars: foe '+ obj +' will be rendered');
            foeRenderIds.push(obj); // push foe id in list
            if (obj in foes) {
                foes[obj].avatar = fnFoes[obj].avatar; // change avatar items in foes;
            }

            var avatar = fnFoes[obj].avatar.split(','); // split avatar string in array
            console.log(avatar);
            console.log(fnFoes[obj]);
            if (document.getElementById('#'+obj)){ // if foe div already exists in avatarDoubles, just delete it
                $('#'+obj).html(); // delete old avatar from doubles
            } else {
                var html ='<div id="foe' + obj + '"></div>'; // if avatar doesn't exist, create it in avatarDoubles
                $('#avatarDoubles').append(html);
            }

            //render avatar
            if (typeof avatar !== 'undefined' && avatar.length > 1) {
               $.map(avatar, function(j,key){
                  console.log(avatar[key]);
                  var name = avatar[key];  
                  db.svgs.get(name).then(function(obj2){
                      var html = "<div class='" + obj2.category + "'  data-name='" + obj2.name + "' data-category='" + obj2.category + "'>" + obj2.svg + "</div>";
                      $('#foe' + obj).append(html);
                      console.log(obj2.name);
                  });

                });
            }                  
        } else {
            console.log('loadAllAvatars: foe '+ obj +' already exists');  
        }
});
```

Comment: You might want to look into [`promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thx, i already did. Unfortunately i couldn't get it working. the problem seems to be the indexedDB-query.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to understand your code but you probably want something like this:

```
function connect() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var request = indexedDB.open();
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
  });
}

function dothings(db, things) {
  var promises = [];
  for(var thing of things) {
    var promise = dothing(db, thing);
    promises.push(promise);
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);
}

function dothing(db, thing) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var tx = db.transaction('svgs');
    var store = tx.objectStore('svgs');
    var request = store.get(thing);
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
  });
}

function foo() {
  var things = getthings();
  connect().then(function(db) {
    return dothings(db, things);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, that looks promising! I'll try to implement it later and tell you if it worked out. I am quite new to coding so probably my code will not meet good coding standards.